# In Python, is there an easier way to make one argument default to another?

Tags: python, function, arguments, default, python-3.3

In Python 3.3.3, when I try

```
def f(x,y=0):
 z = x+y
 return z
```

it works just fine.

However, when I try

```
def f(x,y=x):
 z = x+y
 return z
```

I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

I am aware that I could just do

```
def f(x,y=None):
 y = x if y is None else y
 z = x+y
 return z
```

.

Is there a more concise or otherwise better way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Default arguments are evaluated at function definition time, and at function definition time, we don't have an `x` yet. Explicitly checking for a sentinel value is the best we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fear the simplicity:

```
def f(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = x
    z = x + y
    return z
```

You almost certainly should also have a docstring and better identifier names.

"Concision" in Python is frequently pointlessly complex.

Python is a sublime because you can write very clear code with it.  Don't try to turn it into something it shouldn't be.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x,y=None):
 z = x + (x if y is None else y)
 return z
```

is more concise ...

```
def f(x,y=None):
     return x + (x if y is None else y)
```

is even more concise

```
f = lambda x,y=None:x + (x if y is None else y)
```

is probably as concise as you can make it ...

Comment: This is awful.  You've taken something simple and made it needlessly complicated.

Comment: Forgot to mention `lambda x,y=None:x+[y,x][y is None]`.

Answer (score -2):

While not clearly better, here's one way:

```
def f(x, **kwargs):
    y = kwargs.get('y', x)
    z = x + y
    return z

print f(1)       # -> 2
print f(1, y=2)  # -> 3
```